# How to save files to wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am running my wordpress on localhost, My code retrieves photos from urls and using file_put_contents add them to the current directory, but I need it to add them to /wordpress/wp-content/uploads where wordpress save the manually uploaded files.

```
$Address = "www.xxx.com/" . $file;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$url = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$location = "/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/a.jpg"; 
file_put_contents($location, file_get_contents($url));
if(! function_exists('wp_upload_dir'))
                {
                    define('WP_USE_THEMES',false);
                    require 'wordpress/wp-load.php';
                }
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir(); 
    echo $upload_dir['path'];
    echo $upload_dir['url'];
    echo $upload_dir['subdir'];
```

Comment: What is the problem? You are getting the WP upload directory in your code.

Comment: it does not show anything

Comment: If you mean the last `echo` don't show anything it is most probably because the path to the `wp-load.php` script is wrong in `require 'wordpress/wp-load.php';` and WP is not loading. ¿Where in the WP directory structure is the file in your question located?

Answer (score 2):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_upload_bits

```
// the curl thing from question...results in `$url`
$upload = wp_upload_bits('a.jpg', null, file_get_contents($url));
echo $upload['file'], $upload['url'], $upload['error'];
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand the problem.

This or any equivalent statement should be at the top of the file to load WP:

```
require_once("path/to/wp-load.php");
```

The `path/to/` is relative and depends on the position of your file. If, for example, your file is located in a folder at `wordpress/here`, the path should be something like `"../wp-load.php"`, but that's something you have to figure out.

Try displaying errors so you know what's going on, with a code like this one:

```
ini_set( 'display_errors', TRUE );
error_reporting( E_ALL );
```

Then, add this code:

```
$UploadDir = wp_upload_dir();
$UploadURL = $UploadDir['baseurl'];
$location  = $UploadURL . "/2013/a.jpg";
```

Remove:

```
$location = "/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/a.jpg"; and all code from:

if(! function_exists('wp_upload_dir')) {
```

down to the last line.

Insert `echo` statements in the appropriate places to see the results.

Comment: I did it runs into following error Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_upload_dir() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/Photos/classes/Photos.php on line 36

Comment: Keep trying. That means you enabled the error display and the path to `wp-load.php` is still wrong. From the path in the error, your script is 6 levels below the WP root directory, where the script `wp-load.php` is located. You need something like this `../../../../../../wp-load.php` Remove `../` until there are no errors.

Comment: I gave it an absolute address now it shows the following error, failed to open stream: No such file or directory in, the error is on the second line                                              $location = "Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/uploads";
file_put_contents($location, file_get_contents($url));

Comment: Check [this link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) to have a better idea of `require` and `include` paths.

Comment: I did not see your last comment update. WP seems to be loaded already an your path is working. Your problem now is with `file_put` function, more exactly with the URL parameter.

Comment: yeah but not sure where the problem is I suppose I should open a new question right ?

Comment: It would be better. You are facing a different problem now. Glad I could help with this question.

Comment: ok I have created a new question you may find it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14412888/need-to-save-a-retrieved-photo-from-webservice-to-wordpress