# I can save the file into wordpress but it does not show it

Tags: wordpress, plugins, save

I am running wordpress on localhost, I can successfully save files into upload directory of wordpress using the following code, but wordpress does not show them in its media library, although it shows just those that I upload using its upload feature.

```
require("/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-load.php");

$Addr = "http://www.xxx.com" . $Addr;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Addr);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

ini_set( 'display_errors', TRUE );
error_reporting( E_ALL );

$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir(); 
$location= $upload_dir['basedir']. "/" . "a.jpg";


file_put_contents($location, $output);
echo 'Photo is uploaded';
```

When I go to following address I can see the photos there.

```
http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/
```

I even copied a file manually but it does not show that one as well but when I upload the same file using wordpress itself the file will be shown.

Comment: I am really frustrated it runs into another error :(

Comment: no it shows the following error Warning: file_put_contents(/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/uploads): failed to open stream: Is a directory in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/Photos/classes/Photos.php on line 46

Answer (score 2):

Seems a permission problem, try set 644 with `chmod`:

```
file_put_contents($location, $output);
chmod($location, 0644); // <--- new code
```

Comment: no it did not solve the issue, when it saves the files I cant even open them in my os

Comment: @saeed-pirdost Sorry man, You should try the previous [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14410244/how-to-add-photos-from-a-url-to-wordpress) now that you know `require("/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-load.php");` but hardcode a path like that is not a good practice either...

Comment: can I ask you why when I activate my plugin, its results will be shown on every page ?

Comment: @saeed-pirdost lol, the plugin runs in every page, yes. but you can manage when and what output through [WP hooks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API). You can't write a WP plugin without dive in its [worldwide famous codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/)

Comment: ok thanks back to the current question, the file is now saved on disk but wordpress wont find it .

Comment: @saeed-pirdost WP not find it because have no idea about your file. WP use DB to manage all uploads. If that is what you want, you must to know a lot more about WP. Better take a already working plugin and study its code. Sayonara... :)